# Validation errors when scaffolding a new view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

#### Edit 2:

I fixed the issue by removing one of my POCO classes from the DbSets. This as the start of a process of elimination to see if any of them were the cause of the problem.

The offender was this:

```
public class Error
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas why that borked it?

#### Edit 1:

The errors occur when I try to add a data migration as well. From Package Manager Console:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

SuppliersMVC.Models.Exception: : EntityType 'Exception' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SuppliersMVC.Models.IdentityReference: : EntityType 'IdentityReference' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SuppliersMVC.Models.AssemblyName: : EntityType 'AssemblyName' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SuppliersMVC.Models.CultureInfo: : EntityType 'CultureInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SuppliersMVC.Models.DateTimeFormatInfo: : EntityType 'DateTimeFormatInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Exceptions: EntityType: EntitySet 'Exceptions' is based on type 'Exception' that has no keys defined.
IdentityReferences: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityReferences' is based on type 'IdentityReference' that has no keys defined.
AssemblyNames: EntityType: EntitySet 'AssemblyNames' is based on type 'AssemblyName' that has no keys defined.
CultureInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'CultureInfoes' is based on type 'CultureInfo' that has no keys defined.
DateTimeFormatInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'DateTimeFormatInfoes' is based on type 'DateTimeFormatInfo' that has no keys defined.
```

Here's my DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public virtual DbSet<Error> Errors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PaymentTerm> PaymentTerms { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SupplierDocument> SupplierDocuments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SupplierService> SupplierServices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Voucher> Vouchers { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DevConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

The classes referenced in the errors (`SuppliersMVC.Models.Exception`, `SuppliersMVC.Models.IdentityReference`, etc.) also don't appear in my Object Browser.

It's also worth noting that the project builds without any errors. Output window shows nothing when I attempt to add a migration.

#### Question

I'm trying to scaffold my view so that I can just go in and make necessary changes to the produced code without having to rewrite all the markup myself (the idea is to save time).

There's a few validation errors that appear when I try this though as detailed in the image below, but for quality purposes, I'll also quote them here.

Here's what my ViewModel (that I'm trying to scaffold to) looks like:

```
public class AddEditSupplierViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Services { get; set; }
    public int SelectedRating { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RatingList { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public double Commission { get; set; }
    public int PaymentTermId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PaymentTerms { get; set; }
    public bool Preferred { get; set; }
    public DateTime BEEExpiry { get; set; }
    public string SHEQ { get; set; }

    public AddEditSupplierViewModel()
    {
        var List = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        RatingList = List.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

It looks like the errors continue past the bounds of the error box so I don't think this is all of it, but it doesn't look like this has anything to do with my viewmodel.

I started this as a bare-bones MVC project. I didn't do anything special with it; just added my models to the ApplicationDbContext which builds per ASP.NET Identity as I've done in several projects that don't have these problems.

Any ideas what's going on? How can I get rid of these and scaffold my Views?

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'Unable to retrieve metadata for
>   'SuppliersMVC.Models.AddEditSupplierViewModel'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Exception: : EntityType 'Exception' has no key defined. Define a key for this 
>   entity type.
>
> IdentityReference: : EntityType 'IdentityReference' has no key defined. Define a key for this entity type.
>
> AssemblyName: : EntityType 'AssemblyName' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType
>
> DateTimeFormatInto: : EntityType 'DateTimeFormatInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType
>
> Exceptions: EntityType: EntitySet 'Exceptions is based on type 'Exception' that has no keys defined.
>
> IdentityReferences: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityReferences' is based on type 'IdentityReference that has no keys defined.
>
> AssemblyNames: EntityType: EntitySet 'AssemblyNames' is based on type 'AssemblyNames' that has no keys defined.
>
> CultureInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'CultureInfoes' is based on type 'CultureInfo' that has no keys defined.
>
> DateTimeFormatInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'DateTimeFormatInfoes' is based on type 'DateTimeFOrmatInfo' that has no keys defined.

[image]

Comment: Your view models need to be in a separate folder so they are not associated with EF.

Comment: I thought that simply excluding them from the data model by not adding `public DbSet<viewmodel> viewmodels { get; set; }` to the DbContext would be enough to eliminate association with EF. Is that not the case?

Comment: In any event, I've moved the ViewModels to its own namespace

Comment: It hasn't resolved the issues

Comment: No, you need to put them into a separate folder (say `VIewModels`)

Comment: Yes I did that. This created a new namespace in my app called `ViewModels`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the class into :

```
 public class AddEditSupplierViewModel
 {
    [Key] // add key to Primary Key
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Services { get; set; }
    public int SelectedRating { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RatingList { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public double Commission { get; set; }
    public int PaymentTermId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PaymentTerms { get; set; }
    public bool Preferred { get; set; }
    public DateTime BEEExpiry { get; set; }
    public string SHEQ { get; set; }

    public AddEditSupplierViewModel()
    {
        var List = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        RatingList = List.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

**NOTE :** If the property is named something other than `Id`, you need to add the `[Key]` attribute to it.

Comment: No joy I'm afraid. I should have mentioned that I tried this before I posted the question :/

Comment: The error you are seeing is may be a bug in visual studio. Why don't you manually create an action method, a view (don't select the model in the wizard) and update the view to use your view model as the `model`

Comment: I've been creating my views and action methods manually (I normally do) but these errors are also preventing the project from building so I can't even add a data migration or update the database :/

Comment: Make sure that the "Data context class" textbox is empty in the dialog. If this box is filled with an EntityFramework DB Context, you will get this error. Try removing it